# Open a XML file not knowing the complete name and parse xml

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am using robot framework with RIDE, and for a test I need to find a XML file on my computer and open it to parse the xml and be able to use the datas.
The thing is that I don't know the exact name of the file; the format is *number*NameOfTheFile, so it could be 1NameOfTheFile or 25NameOfTheFile.
How can I use regexp in my keyword? Or any other way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you do it manually - how would you pick the file to use for the verification?
I presume, you are going to look at all the files that are matching a specific name pattern; in Robot Framework you can do that with [OperatingSystem's `List Files In Directory`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#List%20Files%20In%20Directory) keyword, which supports passing a name pattern:

```
${the files}=    List Files In Directory    /the/path/to/the/dir   *NameOfTheFile.xml
```

Now you have a list object with the filenames that match; if it's empty - there's no such file, which may be a problem (depends on your test/reqs, I don't know). If it has a single member - great, that's your file.
And if there are multiple files - that's another "problem". How would you pick the right file manually? It could be that the newest file is the target one - for that you would go over all of them and find the one through [OperatingSystem's `Get Modified Tume`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Get%20Modified%20Time); or it can be the largest; or the number in its suffix would be the biggest. This really depends on your requirements, and what you are trying to achieve.

---

"How would you do it manually" is probably the most important question to ask. Think and break down to steps the individual tasks you would do, and now you have the algorithm; see how to put that in code - and presto, the implementation. This applies to scripts, test cases, and business process automation (e.g. software). 
I was tempted to mark the question for closing, because precisely this - the algorithm - was missing, only the end goal is stated - while SO is for helping in the implementation part. But, here we are :)